# How prevent unhautorized access to file with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

how i can:

- ALLOW access to file from website

AND

- DENY access to file from all which external to website

Using HTACCESS ?

For example website is stored in a webspace associated to domain: xxx.xx. 
Inside a webpage i have a link as:

```
<a href="http://www.xxx.xx/video/example.mp4">LINK</a>
```

And:

- Clicking on LINK then start video correctly

BUT

- Typing from url (for example): `http://www.xxx.xx/video/example.mp4` need return error 403 (denied access) blocking so playing and/or download of file: example.mp4

Thanks for help.

Comment: You have `www.xxx.xx` in both URLs. What's the difference?

Comment: the first url is accessible from webpage. the second url is accessible from direct url. I want allow ONLY which url is accessible from webpage AND NOT from direct url.

Comment: For web server both requests are same. There can be a weak check based on HTTP_REFERRER but that can be spoofed easily.

Comment: I want simply prevent any access to file which not is from internal website. Just if domain not is xxx.xx then need return 403 error (access denied). Can i deny in read files so? How i can to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not easy to write a rule in comments, I am providing a rule which blocks access to a `mp4` file based on `HTTP_REFERER` header value:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?xxx\.xx/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^video/example\.mp4$ - [F,NC]
```

However keep in mind that clients can spoof `HTTP_REFERER` header.